# Apache redirect dynamically one domain to another

Tags: apache, redirect, mod-rewrite

We are currently migrating from one domain to another, I need to write a rewrite rule that will redirect all websites from the old domain to the new one.

I can match if the browser try to access the old domain :

```
RewriteCond "%{HTTP_HOST}" "^(.*).old.com$" [NC]
```

Now I need the rewrite rule that can extract the host before ".old.com" to create the new URL with "xx.new.com". It seems to me that a RewriteRule only contains the path of the page being accessed and not the full URL that would contain the host part.

I would like to do something like this :

```
RewriteRule "^https:\/\/(.*)\.old\.com(.*)$" "https://$1.new.com/$2" [R=301,L]
```

How can this be achieved?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition is good but your rewrite rule is wrong: the regex pattern will be matched against the part of the URL after the hostname and port, and before the query string, so there is no hostname there.

Still, your substitution can back-reference to the pattern matched in `RewriteCond`:

```
RewriteCond "%{HTTP_HOST}" "^(.*).old.com$" [NC]
RewriteRule ^ "https://%1.new.com%{REQUEST_URI}" [R=301,L]
```

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule

Comment: This works exactly as expected. I wasn't aware of back-reference processing, thank you.